# How to fix TNS Doctor Errors

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, tns, nativescript-vue

I'm trying to develop an app on mobile but I got some troubles when I run the command :

```sh
$ tns doctor
✖ WARNING: adb from the Android SDK is not installed or is not configured properly.  
 For Android-related operations, the NativeScript CLI will use a built-in version of adb.
To avoid possible issues with the native Android emulator, Genymotion or connected
Android devices, verify that you have installed the latest Android SDK and
its dependencies as described in http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements 

✖ WARNING: The Android SDK is not installed or is not configured properly. 
 You will not be able to run your apps in the native emulator. To be able to run apps
in the native Android emulator, verify that you have installed the 
latest Android SDK 
and its dependencies as described in 
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements 

✖ Cannot find a compatible Android SDK for compilation. To be able to build for Android, install Android SDK 28 or later. 
 Run `$ sdkmanager` to manage your Android SDK versions. 

✖ You need to have the Android SDK Build-tools installed on your system. You can install any version in the following range: '>=23 <=28'. 
 Run `$ sdkmanager` from your command-line to install required `Android Build Tools`. In case you already have them installed, make sure 
`ANDROID_HOME` environment variable is set correctly. 

You have nativescript-cloud extension installed, so you can execute cloud builds, but your environment is not configured properly and you will not be able to execute local builds. To continue, choose one of the following options: 
Select "Sync to Playground" to enjoy NativeScript without any local setup. All you need is a couple of companion apps installed on your devices.
Select "Configure for Local Builds" to run the setup script and automatically configure your environment for local builds.
Select "Skip Step and Configure Manually" to disregard this option and install any required components manually.
? To continue, choose one of the following options:  (Use arrow keys)
 Sync to Playground 
  Try Cloud Operation 
  Configure for Local Builds 
  Skip Step and Configure Manually
```

Comment: Just follow the setup guide for your machine - [windows](https://docs.nativescript.org/start/ns-setup-win) / [mac](https://docs.nativescript.org/start/ns-setup-os-x).

Comment: Yes it's what i'm trying to do but nothing is working ^^

Comment: That makes your question too broad. Let's know what you tried and where you are failing, may be we could start with Android SDK. Are you on Windows? Did you download the Android SDK on your machine?

Comment: Yes sorry i didn't make make my post really easy to help. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 TS and i installed adb but the error is still here and i think there is a problem : where adb is and the folder where android sdk ( usr/local/lib*android/sdk/tools/) are not at the same place ? Is that normal ?

Comment: >root@salah-pc:/usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools# ls
adb  package.xml  source.properties 

and 

root@salah-pc:/usr/local/lib/android/sdk/tools# la
android  emulator        lib       monitor     proguard           support
bin      emulator-check  mksdcard  NOTICE.txt  source.properties

Comment: And yes i downloaded Android SDK tools only and i added it in the PATH

Comment: As mentioned in docs, what you have installed is just tools. You have to still use further commands to download platforms (api levels) - `sudo $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "tools" "emulator" "platform-tools" "platforms;android-28" "build-tools;28.0.3" "extras;android;m2repository" "extras;google;m2repository"`

Comment: Oh okay I tried to run the command but it doesn't work and it returns to me an error that i saw a lot since i triyng nativescript : ``